# checkbox array recovering old values checked

Tags: arrays, laravel, checkbox, laravel-blade

I would like to retrieve old values in my add form and at the same time recovering data in the edit page stored previously in the database.

here is my code:

```
<div class="row checkbox-offres">
      <legend class="fieldset-label">Skills&nbsp;:</legend>
      @foreach ($skills as $skill)
      <div class="form-group-lg col-lg-6">
        <label>
          <input class="form-check-input @error('skills') is-invalid @enderror" type="checkbox"
            name="skills[]" value='{{$skill->id}}' @foreach($demande->skills as $skill_chosen)
          {{ (is_array(old('skills')) && in_array($skill->id, old('skills'))) ? 'checked' : '' }}
          @endforeach
          > {{$skill->name}}</label>
      </div>
      @endforeach
      @error('skills')
      <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
        {{$errors->first('skills')}}
      </div>
      @enderror
    </div>
```

this code doesn't recovers old values in the add form and doesen't recovers data stored in databse. but recover old in the edit id someone mistake a field it's weird.

```
 {{ $skill_chosen->id == $skill->id ? 'checked' : '' }}
```

it's retrieve data form database but i don't konw how to put that in the condition.

by the way : Demande and Student = has many 
and Skills = many to many. the 3 Tables are in a classic relation ship

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

`{{ is_array(old('skills'))  ? (in_array($skill->id, old('skills')) ? 'checked': '') : ($skill_chosen->id == $skill->id ? 'checked' : '')  }}`

Comment: wow thanks, it works half , i manage to retrieve old data and database in form edit 
but I can’t get get old data in the add form when someone is mistaken on a field.

Comment: i think value='{{$skill->id}}' also include old('skills)  no ?

Comment: Are you returning the values in the controller? *return Redirect::back()->withInput($request->input());*